# Generate a JWT token on jmeter using an RSA-256 private key

Tags: jmeter, jwt, automated-tests

So the thing is I want to run some test cases on jmeter that require a jwt authorization. That jwt must be generated using a private key (RSA-256).

Is there any way I can do this on jMeter?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using:

1. A suitable [JWT Java Client library](https://jwt.io/)
2. A suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223)
3. A piece of [Groovy code](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

Example approach assuming having [JJWT library](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt) with dependencies in [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)

```
def generator = java.security.KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("RSA");
generator.initialize(2048, new java.security.SecureRandom())
def keyPayr = generator.generateKeyPair()

def now = java.time.Instant.now()

def clientId = 'foo'

def jwt = io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts.builder()
        .setAudience('https://example.com')
        .setIssuedAt(Date.from(now))
        .setExpiration(Date.from(now.plus(5L, java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit.MINUTES)))
        .setIssuer(clientId)
        .setSubject(clientId)
        .setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
        .signWith(keyPayr.private)
        .compact()

log.info('Token: ' + jwt)
```

[image]